# How to make JavaScript choose one of three options at random?

Tags: javascript, random

I am learning JavaScript and I want to make a simple rock paper scissors game. I want to make the computer choose the number 1, 2, or 3 at random and make the answer a variable called computerResponse. How do I do this?

```
var computerResponse = ???;
```

If this question is unclear please tell me and I will try to make it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random); try it and see how far you get.

Comment: Also, if you search SO for `javascript rock paper scissors` you'll find a bunch of similar questions.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? It's a duplicate, sure, but the asker is obviously new to this site, and doesn't deserve a hostile downvote right off the bat...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because the asker has apparently made no effort to try to solve the problem himself.

Comment: @Barmar: maybe they came here and just asked a question before even thinking about searching. maybe their search term wasn't the best, and they didn't get great results. sure, we should be encouraging 'the correct' behaviour, but I just think a downvote here is a bit heavy-handed

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a complete newbie to JavaScript and this is the first time I've attempted to do something like a game. I have looked (I looked for several hours) but didn't find anything. I'll look more thoroughly next time. Sorry for any inconvenience and special thanks to those who answered.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var computerResponse = getRandomInt(1, 3);
```

Taken from MDN's [**documentation on `Math.random()`.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
```

Comment: you mean .ceil(), although .roof() would be a useful alias :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this below javascriptscript code that would be fetched random numbers...

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)